# Format of Google BigQuery public ngram dataset?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to use Google books ngram dataset in my project, it is available on BigQuery but the format is not explained.

Can anybody clarify it or point to the description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this discussion in the [official Bigquery google-group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/bigquery-discuss/OT_W0ayVSvg/xQQD4zlsTk4J)